# Access Data From active window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing one universal application in **c#** in which i want text from any active window. When ever user press hot keys my application will launch with active windows text data.

It is one spell checker application.
My Problem is how to access text from Microsoft Document.
I Tried All system32.dll function

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, IntPtr msg,
           int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, int ProcessId);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(500000);

        int foregroundWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint remoteThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindowHandle,0);
        uint currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

        //AttachTrheadInput is needed so we can get the handle of a focused window in another app
        AttachThreadInput(remoteThreadId, currentThreadId, true);
        //Get the handle of a focused window
        int focused = GetFocus();
        //Now detach since we got the focused handle
        AttachThreadInput(remoteThreadId, currentThreadId, false);

        //Get the text from the active window into the stringbuilder
        SendMessage(focused, WM_GETTEXT, builder.Capacity, builder);
        Console.WriteLine("Text in active window was " + builder);
        builder.Append(" Extra text");

        //Change the text in the active window
        SendMessage(focused, WM_SETTEXT, 0, builder);
        //Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Read();
```

But This will return text from only notepad,browser addressbar, wordpad, etc..
But actually its not working in microsoft product like ms office ,excel..etc.

I want text from any active window for spell check can any one help me for this.?

Thanx In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the text from any application...but you can develop the keystroke application which can get the keystroke from any window and save it to your application....I developed key stroke application in c# but that is not working correctly...It detect the key strokes from any window but disturbed when caps lock key is pressed....

Answer (score 0):

No it is possible..
Because my client had give me his old application in which it will work..
it will work with word,excel,ppt,notepad,wordpad etc..
But Now he wants it for universal kind..
And He gives me the .exe file for that...so i cant check the code..
And there is no situation that i ask him for his old application code..so i cant get the code of old application too...

So there is fix that this is working ....